# How do I determine the amount of enzyme needed to liquefy a known quantity of starch substrate?

Tags: mash, sugar, malt, mash-ph, brewing-enzymes

I have an enzyme preparation (powdery form) with an activity of 1045 U/g which I would like to use in mashing a 70 g of grain whose starch percentage is at 67%.
How do I determine the quantity (in grams) of the enzyme preparation needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The amount is dependent on desired speed and temperature constraint, possibly the condition of the grain. Make test batches and time how long they take to reach full conversion under your conditions.

Any amount of enzyme held at a temperature within its active range will eventually convert all of the starch.

Too slow of a conversion and you risk contamination or simply being impractical. Too much enzyme is a waste of enzyme, the only lasting problem would be in cases where you want to stop the enzyme halfway through conversion because the change could be happening faster than you can act.